# How to prevent small locations from being plotted as points when using GeoListPlot?

Tags: plotting, map, geography, geographics

When a location is too small, [GeoListPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoListPlot.html) marks that location using a point on the map. For example,
`GeoListPlot[{Entity["Country", "Ireland"],  Entity["City", {"Atlanta", "Georgia", "UnitedStates"}],  Entity["City", {"Savannah", "Georgia", "UnitedStates"}]}]`

results in the attached image. I have a list of lots of countries and locations, and I want to disable plotting of smaller locations (e.g., the red point in attached example). How can I go about doing this without manually removing said small locations from the list?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "manual"? Is this OK? `locations = {Entity["Country", "Ireland"], Entity["City", {"Atlanta", "Georgia", "UnitedStates"}], Entity["City", {"Savannah", "Georgia", "UnitedStates"}]}; GeoListPlot[Select[locations, FreeQ[#, "City"] &]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon This works great if there are only cities in the list, but there are also small countries in the list that are shown as dots. For example, the code does not work with Vatican City. `locations = {Entity["Country", "Ireland"], 
  Entity["Country", "VaticanCity"]}; GeoListPlot[
 Select[locations, FreeQ[#, "City"] &]]`

Comment: You can use a size threshold, e.g., `GeoListPlot[Select[locations, FreeQ[#, "City"] && CountryData[#, "Area"] > Quantity[10^3, "Kilometers"^2] &]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon the size threshold idea works great with tuning, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red points are added with `Inset`. If `gp` is the original plot, the following removes the points.

```
gp /. Inset[__] -> Nothing
```